# In React with Redux, when should I use syncHistoryWithStore

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I can see sometimes people just use `browserHistory` as `history`, like

```
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router'
const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}></Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
)
```

but in some projects, people are using `syncHistoryWithStore`, like

```
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

render(
  <Root store={store} history={history} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

when should I use the latter? why `syncHistoryWithStore` is needed?

thanks

Comment: I believe it's mostly for debugging purposes. when using time traveling add-on for redux this ensures your navigation stack will time travel as well.